# Como ocultar el contenido de un checkbox desmarcado?

Tags: javascript, html, css

necesito que el contenido de un checkbox desmarcado se oculte al marcar otro checkbox.

Imagen del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Js**

```
    <script>
$('#alternar').click(function(){
    $('#prueba').toggle();
});
$(".placeholder").select2({
    placeholder: "Make a Selection",
    allowClear: true
});
 </script>
<script>
$('#alternarpaypal').click(function(){
    $('#pruebapaypal').toggle();
});
$(".placeholder").select2({
    placeholder: "Make a Selection",
    allowClear: true
}); 
</script>
```

Html:

```
<input type="radio" class="new-control-input" name="custom-radio-2" id="alternar"/>
    
    
    <div id="prueba">
    "CONTENIDO CHECKBOX 1"

                                        </div>

  <input type="radio" class="new-control-input" name="custom-radio-1" id="alternarpaypal"/>
      
    <div id="pruebapayal">
                  "CONTENIDO CHECKBOX 2"
</div>
```

**Css**

```
 <style>
#prueba{
  
   display:none
}
#pruebapaypal{
  
  display:none
}

</style>
```

lo que necesito es que se oculte el contenido del checkbox que este desmarcado
no tengo mucho conocimiento en js y necesito lograr esto, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creando una clase de estilos con un display:none, y utilizando classList.add y classList.remove para agregarla y removerla puedes conseguir ese comportamiento.
Adicionalmente cambie el radio por un checkbox.

```js
const contenido2 = document.getElementById("pruebapayal")
const checkbox2 = document.getElementById("alternarpaypal");

checkbox2.addEventListener("change", (evento) => {
  if (evento.target.checked) {
    contenido2.classList.add("pruebapayal");
  }else {
    contenido2.classList.remove("pruebapayal");
  }
  
});
```

```css
.pruebapayal {

  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="new-control-input" name="custom-radio-2" id="alternar"/>
    
    
    <div id="prueba">
    "CONTENIDO CHECKBOX 1"

                                        </div>

  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input" name="custom-radio-1" id="alternarpaypal"/>
      
    <div id="pruebapayal">
                  "CONTENIDO CHECKBOX 2"
</div>
```